# Facebook hometown graph api

Tags: php, facebook

I am currently getting data from a users profile when they login through facebook, I want to store this data for signup process on my site. When accessing "hometown" it lists it as one such as:

```
London, Westminster, United Kingdom
```

The hometown is in an array as follows:

```
>  [hometown] => Array
>         (
>             [id] => 000000000
>             [name] => London, Westminster, United Kingdom
>         )
```

I access the town name by using the code

```
<?php echo $me['hometown']['name']; ?>
```

Would it be possible to have each part single? So that I could have, town, country etc

I am using Facebook php SDK
Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
$hometown=explode(",",$me['hometown']['name']);

echo $hometown[0]; //London
echo $hometown[1]; //Westminster
echo $hometown[2]; //United Kingdom
```

edited: changed to explode as "split()" is deprecated as of php 5.3

Comment: Perfect, just what I wanted :) Thanks!

Comment: Might need to use trim($hometown[0]); so that you remove the whitespace from the parts. otherwise it could be " United Kingdom" instead of "United Kingdom". Just a little tweak :D

Comment: I've noticed the format isn't always consistent. Sometimes it'll be: {suburb}, {region}, {country}. Other times (such as with capital cities), it'll just be {city}, {country}, as with "Paris, France".

Comment: Splitting a string like this is only as consistent as the data you feed it. If you know that there are only ever going to be city/suburb/country OR city/country you could accommodate that just by going if(count($hometown)==2) { //do city/country } elseif(count($hometown)==3) { //do city/suburb/country }

Comment: :O What if the cities name has a comma in it? Then you'll have to use a parser to escape it.